# Write pre-commit that *checks* if jupyter notebooks have output cleared

Tags: python, git, jupyter-notebook, hook, nbconvert

I know you can use `jupyter nbconvert --clear-output --inplace <file>` (per [here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html)) to clear the output of a jupyter notebook. I'm wondering if there's an easy way to *check* if output has been cleared in a pre-commit hook. That way I can fail the pre-commit if it hasn't and force the user to try again. Thanks!

Comment: Clear and compare with the original?

Comment: I guess this works. I was hoping (maybe naively) that there was an option like `--check` that just tells you if it's already cleared or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [nbstripout](https://github.com/kynan/nbstripout/) as a pre-commit hook.

```
repos:
- repo: https://github.com/kynan/nbstripout
  rev: 0.5.0
  hooks:
    - id: nbstripout
```

You could possibly modify it with `--dry-run` to not modify any files. I have not tried that, though.

Comment: Looks like using `--dry-run` would not work in a pre-commit hook b/c it always returns `0` (success), even if files were to change (issue in GH [here](https://github.com/kynan/nbstripout/issues/159))